# Fixed UITextField's character length

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can limit the characters of `UITextField` without using delegate methods. Im using `UITableView` in which i have `UITextField` in cell and used in different position within same screen and i want to limit text field on certain position `UITableViewCell`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same problem some time ago. However not using delegates is not correct way. you should use delegate and control the behaviour depending upon the position.

1. Make a function in your tableViewCell class, Let's say that's

   ```
   -(void)setMyCellTag:(NSInteger)tag
   {
       self.tag = tag;
   }
   ```
2. Now call this method from your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** function as,

   ```
   [cell setMyCellTag:indexPath.row];
   ```
3. Use condition in UITextField delegate method that,

   ```
   if(self.tag == yourposition)
   {
      //Do Something
   }
   ```

Simple. Thanks for reading.

Comment: let me check it and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 1 // set your limit
}
```

make sure textfield delegate

Comment: @Najam code is working fine with tag and delegate. but i want without delegate.